# Ctrl+Tab in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, development-environment, customization

**My Question:**

Is there a way to set up Visual Studio to use the Style of Ctrl+Tabbing so that it doesn't remember the order of tabs and just goes to the next tab or previous tab depending on the usage of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key?

Maybe a registry setting (I think that there was something for this in TweakUI for Windows XP)?  or a program setting, or even some sort of add-on.  Bonus if the change screen doesn't pop up anymore too.

**More Explanation:**

There are two styles of how <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> can work.

In Windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will remember which application last had focus and it will switch between things in that order.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will put you right back to where you started.

In Google Chrome (for example) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will switch to the next tab instantly.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will take you one tab over, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will take you three tabs back.

The first way benefits people who have a lot of things open and are just switching between the few things that they are working on.  The second way benefits people who are working on several files at once and are aware of what they're doing in each file.

I prefer the first style because the second one gets me lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027/changing-ctrltab-behavior-for-moving-between-document-in-visual-studio) which covers this topic, however it doesn't look like theres a solid solution.

There is also this [workaround](http://mrspeaker.webeisteddfod.com/2006/10/12/tab-un-stupidifier/), but theres no guarantee on the reliability of the method.

Comment: In fact, the workaround is actually known to be broken, sadly...