# Better Tab Navigation in gVim

Tags: vim, editor, behavior

How can I get tabs in gVim to work like they do in most good IDEs? I say gVim specifically because that is the version of Vim that I use but I am open to alternatives.

#### I want the following things for my tabs:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> goes to the MRU (most recently used) tab.
2. Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple times continues to change to the next most recently used tab every time you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
3. When ctags are built and working and you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, if this takes you to a different file it should open that file in a new tab or if a tab with that file is already open it should switch to that one.
4. Easy tab reordering with the mouse just by dragging them around.

I am posting all these as a single question because I am hoping there is a good single solution that will do all or most of these things instead of having to hack each customization in individually. I would think this would be the preferred behavior by most of us.

Comment: Each his own but I hate the MRU behavior with a passion. A good read on that is http://www.mrspeaker.net/2006/10/12/tab-un-stupidifier/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027/changing-ctrltab-behavior-for-moving-between-document-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim has no built in MRU. There is at least [one plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=521) for that, though, but I've never used it.

The tabs in Vim are not the same as the tabs in your IDE, they are more like perspectives. The equivalent of your IDE's tabs in Vim are buffers and "(split)windows". There are a number of ways to work with buffers including [some](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching) [native](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Buffers) [ones](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ) and [a number of third party plugins. Some of these plugins have MRU-like features.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=buffer%20switching&script_type=&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search)

The Vim wiki has a bunch of pages [about](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_tab_pages) [tabs.](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Quick_tips_for_using_tab_pages)

Comment: I agree with comment that tabs in Vim are different (and purposely so).  However neither buffers nor buffers/windows in Vim are completely analogous to tabs in other editors or IDE's.  Moreover, buffers, windows, and tabs in Vim lack (good) built-in shortcut keys for navigation.  The commands for navigating are there, the user just needs to map the commands to keys as desired.  Some ideas for tab shortcuts (similar to what OP asks for) are here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Alternative_tab_navigation

Comment: Yes, buffers and windows are not completely analogous but I thought they were close enough. Tabs are VERY different, though. And poorly named. I totally missed the page on alternative tab navigation, you probably should submit it as an answer.

Comment: Actually I think buffers by themselves (i.e., without split windowing) are probably closest analogue to tabs in other editors.  Their operation is pretty similar to what you'd have in a tabbing editor that doesn't show the little-tab-thingies and makes you navigate between tabs some other way.  So for people new to Vim best way to start out is probably to use buffers with one of the buffer-navigating plugins like Fuzzy Finder:  http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984

Comment: Thanks! After reading this I realized I was lacking in knowledge of buffers. The Vim buffer FAQ was very helpful. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ I ended up using the bufexplorer plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42 This allows me to just press \be to switch to the buffer explorer. This shows a list of buffers in MRU order. I navigate to the one I want with hjkl and then I can press Enter to open it right there or t to open it in a tab which will open an existing tab if one is already open for this file. This is almost exactly what I wanted. Even better in fact!

Comment: Actually I still miss pressing Ctrl+tab for a really fast MRU tab switch to the most recently used tab. It would be nice to have that in addition to the bufexplorer plugin.

Comment: Now I have Ctrl+tab working too with this in my _vimrc: ":nmap <C-Tab> \bej<Enter>". I tried this to get it working with pressing tab twice but it does not work: ":nmap <C-Tab-Tab> \bejj<Enter>" Any help?

Comment: It works with ":nmap <C-Tab><C-Tab> \bejj<Enter>" but it is slow.