# Is Ctrl+PageUp/PageDown working in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I checked the default shortcuts and they show up in the global context, but I am still not able to switch between tabs using these keys.

Any ideas why they are not working?

[image]

Comment: In my default installation of Visual Basic 2010 express, ctrl+pageup/pagedn seems to cycle through the different subroutines in my code... which is actually pretty useful. Ctrl+tab opens up a alt+tab style menu that lets me choose which tab I want. Are you trying to modify the shortcut keys from defaults?

Comment: No actually I didn't change any hotkeys, they were set like this. I will take a screenshot. Also when I used Ctrl+PageDown, it just moves the caret to the end of the currently visible section of the text editor.

Comment: Just because they're assigned to one command doesn't mean they're not simultaneously assigned to a *different* command. The two might be fighting.

Comment: Yeah but why would MS do this out of the box? It shows 4 different hotkeys for Ctrl+PageUp/Down.

Comment: I don't have time to read through this completely, but this may help since it seems to have commentary from a Microsoft developer: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/571750/window-nexttab-and-window-previoustab-keybindings-do-not-work-on-form-designer-tabs

Answer (score 13):

There is a solution (utilizing the "Productivity Power Tools" extension) outlined in a reply to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027/changing-ctrltab-behavior-for-moving-between-document-in-visual-studio).

I found that using the "Press shortcut keys:" and "Shortcut currently user by:" controls in the options dialog (Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard) helped me identify problematic duplicate mappings quickly.

[image]