# Productivity Power Tools 2013 does not install Window.NextDocumentWellTab?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Previously (VS2010) I solved the insane Ctrl+Tab behavior using Productivity Power Tools and re-mapping Ctrl+Tab to Window.NextDocumentWellTab.

I have since installed the trial version of Visual Studio 2013 Professional and the latest Feb 2014 version of Productivity Power Tools. Unfortunately the Window.NextDocumentWellTab does not exist. Is this a known problem, will it work when I upgrade to the paid version of VS?

*This question explains why the default Ctrl+Tab behavior in Visual Studio makes me want to tear my eyeballs out and smash my head on the wall:*
[Changing Ctrl + Tab behavior for moving between documents in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027/changing-ctrl-tab-behavior-for-moving-between-documents-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have the same problem and can't find a solution.

Comment: Never found a good solution. I managed to bind Ctrl+Tab to "Window.NextTab (Global)" which works OK - however it only cycles the visible tabs.

Comment: OK Thanks for following up; appreciate it