# Is there a way to map Ctrl-1..9 or Alt-1..9 to tabs in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Just as in any web browser and in most editors, where you're able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to go the first tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to the second, etc. I'd like to have the same functionality in Visual Studio 2013.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Why not just use ctrl-tab?

Comment: Ctrl-Tab becomes completely useless once you have more than two tabs, if you have 5-10 like I do all the time, it just becomes the same as picking one at random.

Comment: I didn't realize ctrl-tab jumped in the order they were last active in.  This accepted answer has the behavior I was expecting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027/changing-ctrl-tab-behavior-for-moving-between-documents-in-visual-studio?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

[Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com/) (commercial, developed by me) with [Navigator add-in](http://www.tabsstudio.com/documentation/addins/navigator.html) supports such keyboard navigation for tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) provide a similar (free) feature:

> ### More Commands for Navigation
>
> Using Ctrl+Alt+Page Down and Page Up to navigate between tabs (including pinned) in visual order.
>
> - Activate a specific pinned tab by Ctrl+Num Pad 1 through 0
> - Activate a specific regular tab by Ctrl+Alt+Num Pad 1 through 0