# How to disable MRU behavior in VS2013 upon tab close

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have already remapped ctl+tab and ctl+shift+tab to Window.NextTab and Window.PreviousTab.

But when I call File.Close, Visual Studio 2013 still uses MRU to decide which tab to bring to the foreground, which usually results in focus jumping somewhere unepxected.  I would like to change this behavior so that the tab right after the just-closed one (to the right in the tab well) is brought to the foreground (if it exists).  This would make VS's behavior match that of ff, chrome, notepad++ etc.

I've tried a bunch of extensions, and while many of them change or create their own next / previous tab functions, none seems to make a new version of File.Close.

Does anyone know if this is possible or the identity of any extensions which do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command created in [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) instead of File.Close to activate next tab after close:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        dte = DTE;
        if (IsCommandAvailable("Window.NextTab"))
        {
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Window.NextTab");
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Window.PreviousTab");
        }
        if (IsCommandAvailable("File.Close"))
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.Close");
    }

    private bool IsCommandAvailable(string commandName)
    {
        EnvDTE80.Commands2 commands = dte.Commands as EnvDTE80.Commands2;
        if (commands == null)
            return false;

        EnvDTE.Command command = commands.Item(commandName, 0);
        if (command == null)
            return false;

        return command.IsAvailable;
    }

    private EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte;
}
```

**Update** A probably better implementation that prevents potential visual side effects:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    dte = DTE;
    if (IsCommandAvailable("Window.NextTab"))
    {
        EnvDTE.Window w = DTE.ActiveWindow;
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Window.NextTab");
        w.Close();
    }
    else if (IsCommandAvailable("File.Close"))
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.Close");
}
```

Comment: Great! I'm already using your "tabs studio" - this would be great to have in there by default!

Comment: Hmm, this kind of works, unless you're at the last tab.  It also has visual side effects (you can see it moving forward and back).  I wonder if there's a way to just store the identity of the physically next tab & switch to that after close, instead?

Comment: I've added a probably better implementation that prevents potential visual side effects, but I don't know how to prevent the activation of the first tab when closing the last one.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work right - it's still jumping around somewhat unpredictably.

Comment: @fastmultiplication For Tabs Studio v3.7.0 I've created the AfterClose add-in to activate the next tab on close.