# VS 2017 - Close tabs to right

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How is it possible to **Close the tabs to the right** in MS Visual Studio 2017?

The VS2017 still lacks this functionality and the plugin (CloseTabsToRight.vsix) I used in previous version (VS2015) doesn't seem to be installable upon this version of VS ("This extension is already installed to all applicable products").

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the extension?

Comment: Yes, see the installation message: "This extension is already installed to all applicable products"

Comment: What i meant is did you properly uninstall and then install. Sometimes when I had VS2013 and VS2015 installed, plugins did not work unless I completely uninstalled them from VS2013 and then install in VS2015. (Also, this plugin's code is on github, so a chance to make it work with 2017 if you fix it)

Comment: I tried to uninstall and install and it only offers to install on VS2015 (not VS2017). Yes, I know about being on GitHub, in a worse case it will take a funny weekday ;)

Comment: That's the spirit!

Comment: create an issue on github so that the developer can provide a VS2017 compatible version: https://github.com/billpratt/CloseTabsToRight/issues

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237715/how-to-disable-mru-behavior-in-vs2013-upon-tab-close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New version of **Close Tabs To Right** plugin compat with VS2017 is available already through Extensions and Updates.