# Excel-like switching between open tabs in Visual Studio editor

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio I would like to be able to switch between open documents in the text editor just like I do in Excel or in a web browser - `Ctrl-PgUp / Down` moves me to the next and previous tabs in the order they appear on the screen.

I am trying to reproduce the same behavior in VS2015/17, but all I find is `Window.NextDocumentWindow` / `PrevDocumentWindow` commands, which do achieve a similar effect but they switch between open files **not** in their screen order, which is very annoying.

Is there an extension or macro of some kind which achieves the behavior I want?

Comment: *very annoying* indeed, I wonder what the idea is behind VS (and other editors) defaulting to use 'recently opened' (or whatever it is) order instead os creen order

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027/changing-ctrl-tab-behavior-for-moving-between-documents-in-visual-studio

Comment: @SergeyVlasov thanks, that's exactly it.. Possible duplicate of [Changing Ctrl + Tab behavior for moving between documents in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027/changing-ctrl-tab-behavior-for-moving-between-documents-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @SergeyVlasov this is great! I ended up overriding 'Ctrl+PgUp/Down' to Window.PrevioustTab/NextTab, and it makes a great difference - very convenient!