# Ctrl+Shift+Tab in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2017, hotkeys

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and have followed the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4099033) to change the behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to next and previous tab, respectively.

Problem is, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works fine, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> only switches to the previous tab when the current document is not a Web Form or similar (e.g. master page). On those pages, the combo switches between Source, Design and Split view instead. How can I disable this behaviour?

I've looked through the keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio settings and haven't found any others that are mapped to that combination. I've even disabled Web Forms designer (so only Source view is available), but it doesn't help, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> simply doesn't do anything then.

Answer (score 2):

Set the shortcut keys for the `Window.PreviousTabAndAddToSelection` command in the **HTML Editor Source View** (instead of **Global**) to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. This has the minor side effect of selecting the previous tab when navigating away from a web form tab, but successfully avoids the unexpected behavior of taking you to the split or design sub tabs.